# Why did so many questions I've answered get bumped to the Arqade homepage recently?

Tags: support, questions, community-user

Over the course of the weekend [five](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272347/fallout-3-trouble-on-the-homefront-trophy-isnt-unlocking) [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/339710/why-cant-i-see-the-nuka-world-map) [I've](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174466/are-vats-aiming-bugs-in-falloutnew-vegas-really-that-preventive/355167#355167) [answered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131960/why-do-i-get-a-there-are-no-known-resources-here-message-when-calling-for-scav/355064#355064) [were](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280144/my-x-01-power-armor-keeps-appearing-in-different-parts-of-my-settlement-but-i-do/355075#355075) bumped to the homepage of Arqade. Before this no questions I've asked or answered have been bumped by [Community](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) before (to my knowledge). Four of the five questions only had one answer - the answer I posted, which I also thought was an interesting trend.

Of course, it wasn't exclusively questions and answers posted by me. I did notice quite a few other questions were bumped to the front page as well. To me, it seemed like more bumps than usual.

What is the criteria for a question/answer to be bumped to the front page and why were there so many over the this weekend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The community user bumps questions that have not gotten much attention; namely, the question is about a month old, its score is not negative, and it has received no upvoted or accepted answers. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/372310) for more details.

Comment: Just an interesting coincidence then? Fair enough.